# MS Word: Create Table of Figures with two SEQIdentifiers in it via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

My goal is to create a TOC with two SEQIdentifiers in it.
It is described and answered [HERE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2007/referencing-repeated-sequence-identifiers-in-a-toc/232651c5-3100-421a-bd39-abed0dee55d2), though the given answer is manually configured, and I want to activate it with a macro.

**Brief description**
I have a sequential Figures throughout the document which can be gathered with Table of figures `{SEQ \c "Figure"}`.
The Figure structure is as follows:
`Figure {STYLEREF 1 \s}-{SEQ Figure \*Arabic \s 1}` - Result with 'Figure 1-1' for example.

The client request is to add "Point Figure", meaning between two figures: Figure 1-1 and Figure 1-2 the client can add Figure 1-1.A, Figure 1-1.B and so on.
Here is how I've initially created the sturcture:
`Figure {STYLEREF 1 \s}-{SEQ Figure \*Arabic \c}.{SEQ PointFigure \* Alphabetic \s 1}`.

**The problem now is that I can not include both of them in a single Table of Figures.**

**Trying to implement the given answer:**
So, my next approach was starting to implement the answer given in the link above.
The given answer by the way is as follow:

- Bookmark the seq field with a special name - in the example it's tablea
- refer to the reference by `{ SEQ Table \r { REF tablea } }`

Here is my code followed by explanation and my problem:

```
Sub createPointFigure()
Dim rng As Range
Dim fld As Field
Dim searchText As String

Set rng = Selection.Range
rng.InsertAfter "Figure "
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Set fld = rng.Fields.Add(rng, wdFieldEmpty, "StyleRef 1 \s", False)
Set rng = fld.result
'Move focus after the inserted field
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
rng.InsertAfter "-"
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.Fields.Add rng, wdFieldEmpty, "SEQ Figure \c", False

' select the entire inserted text
Selection.MoveRight wdWord, 4, wdExtend
searchText = Selection.Text
Set rng = Selection.Range

' Search for the specific figure in text
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
While Not found And Selection.Start <> 1
    findText searchText, False
    For Each fld In Selection.Fields
        If fld.Type = wdFieldSequence Then
            ' look for the original seq field
            If InStr(1, fld.Code.Text, "\s 1", vbTextCompare) Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next fld
    If found Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Selection.Text, Selection
    Else
        ' Collapse to the beginning and keep looking for the next one
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

The findText method:

```
Sub findText(searchParam As String, forwardDirection)
With Selection.find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = searchParam
    .Forward = forwardDirection
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
End With
End Sub
```

**Explanation:**

- Temporary create the closest Figure text
- Search backward until finding the appropriate figure (keep looking if found a sequence field with `\c`).
- Once found, create a new bookmark with the name
- Construct the field as the answer suggests (Not implemented in the code)

**Problems**

- Testing fails in the insert bookmark line:
  `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Selection.Text, Selection`
  Apparently, Bookmark cannot contain numbers and symbols in it.
  How can I distinguish a reusable bookmark? For the next time I'll Create this Figure structure, I would like to reuse the same Bookmark.
- All this work has huge overhead. Is there a simpler solution to accomplish my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Bookmark names must be unique in a document. Bookmark names may not begin with a number and may not contain certain characters. You might look at using TC fields in combination with the SEQ fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @CindyMeister guidance, here is an elegant answer for my problem.

**Point Figure configuration:**
`Figure {STYLEREF 1 \s}-{SEQ Figure \c}.{SEQ PointFigure \* Alphabetic \s 1}. Figure Text *Style Separator* {TC "{STYLEREF "Figure Title"}" \f F}`

**Table of Figures Configuration:**
`{TOC \f F \c "Figure"}`

**Remarks:**

- Figure style in my example is configured as "Figure Title"
- The `{TC}` must be of a different style in order for STYLEREF to work.
  For that I've used Style Separator (Ctrl + Alt + Return). Character style is another option I think.
- All {} brackets in the code examples are Word Fields (Ctrl + F9)
- I inserted the Point Figure text as an AutoText, which is added via Macro.
- In order to achieve unique point numbering for each 'Figure 1-1' text, I've added a reset field before each one: `{SEQ PointFigure \h \r 0}`